# Google Data Studio - Max Record Limit?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a table in google bigquery with 1.4mil records and parcel number as a unique field, I need to be able to extract the data as a csv.

However, when I explore in data studio and break it down by parcel, data studio puts a limit of exactly 1.1mil records, even worse, when I export it as a .csv there are only 750k lines.

Is there a limit in data studio?

Please help!!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Currently (March 2019), there's a limit of ~1m rows when fetching data from BigQuery.

If you are trying to extract 1m+ rows as CSV, ideally, you should be doing it from the BigQuery end. See [Exporting BigQuery table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data). Data Studio should work as a data exploration tool on top of BigQuery.

Comment: Do you have any reference on that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata